# Convert SQL query (with outer join and datediff) to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, outer-join

I have this SQL query that needs to be converted to LINQ.I am new to LINQ and the outer join makes it more difficult for me to convert this query into LINQ.

```
select distinct ls.crew, sd.ambulance, case_number from log_sheet ls
left outer join shift_detail sd on ls.crew = sd.crew 
and sd.time_on between dateadd(d,-1,'2013-05-30 21:48:04.000') and '2013-05-30 21:48:04.000' and (sd.time_off > '2013-05-30 21:48:04.000' or sd.time_off is null)
where ls.time_out between dateadd(d,-1,'2013-05-30 21:48:04.000') and '2013-05-30 21:48:04.000' and ('2013-05-30 21:48:04.000' <= ls.time_clear or ls.time_clear is null)
and (sd.ambulance = 58 or ls.crew = null)
union all
select distinct ls.crew, sd.ambulance, case_number from log_hist ls
left outer join shift_detail sd on ls.crew = sd.crew and sd.time_on between dateadd(d,-1,'2013-05-30 21:48:04.000') and '2013-05-30 21:48:04.000' and (sd.time_off > '2013-05-30 21:48:04.000' or sd.time_off is null)
where ls.time_out between dateadd(d,-1,'2013-05-30 21:48:04.000') and '2013-05-30 21:48:04.000' and ('2013-05-30 21:48:04.000' <= ls.time_clear or ls.time_clear is null)
and (sd.ambulance = 58 or ls.crew = null)
```

Can someone please help? My failed attempt looks like this:

```
var shiftDetail = _dispatchRepository.FindQueryable<Domain.Model.ShiftDetail>();

            var logsheet = _repository.FindQueryable<Domain.Model.LogSheet>()
                .Where(ls => ((ls.time_out >= SqlFunctions.DateAdd("dd", -1, criteria.MRxIncident_Timestamp)) && (ls.time_out <= criteria.MRxIncident_Timestamp))
                        && (criteria.MRxIncident_Timestamp <= ls.time_clear || ls.time_clear == null) && (ls.crew==null));

            var shiftDetailQuery = from l in logsheet
                                   join sd in shiftDetail on l.crew equals sd.crewID into LeftJoin
                                   from sd in LeftJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                   select new MRxCaseSearchResults
                                   {
                                       CaseNumber = l.case_number,
                                       Crew = l.crew,
                                       Ambulance = sd.ambulance,
                                       OfficerNo = sd.officer_no
                                   };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably has some errors but might get you on your way:

```
var dt = new DateTime(2013, 05, 30, 21, 48, 04);

var shiftDetailFiltered = _repository.FindQueryable<Domain.Model.ShiftDetail>()
    .Where(x => x.time_on >= dt.AddDays(-1)) && x.time_on <= dt)
    .Where(x => x.time_off == null || x.time_off > dt);

var q1 = _repository.FindQueryable<Domain.Model.LogSheet>()
.Join(shiftDetailFiltered, ls => ls.crew, sd => sd.crew, (ls, sd) => new { ls, sd })
.DefaultIfEmpty()
.Where(x => x.ls.time_out >= dt.AddDays(-1) && x.ls.time_out <= dt)
.Where(x => dt < x.ls.time_clear == null || x.ls.time_clear)
.Where(x => x.sd.ambulance == 58 || x.ls.crew == null)
.Select(x => new MRxCaseSearchResults
    { 
        CaseNumber = l.case_number,
        Crew = x.ls.crew, 
        Ambulance = x.sd.ambulance, 
        OfficerNo = x.ls.officer_no 
    })
.Distinct();


var q2 = _repository.FindQueryable<Domain.Model.LogHist>()
.Join(shiftDetailFiltered, ls => ls.crew, sd => sd.crew, (ls, sd) => new { ls, sd })
.DefaultIfEmpty()
.Where(x => x.ls.time_out >= dt.AddDays(-1) && x.ls.time_out <= dt)
.Where(x => dt < x.ls.time_clear == null || x.ls.time_clear)
.Where(x => x.sd.ambulance == 58 || x.ls.crew == null)
.Select(x => MRxCaseSearchResults
    { 
        CaseNumber = l.case_number,
        Crew = x.ls.crew, 
        Ambulance = x.sd.ambulance, 
        OfficerNo = x.ls.officer_no 
    })
.Distinct();

var union = q1.Union(q2);

var result = union.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

The portion you have so far should be more like (assuming that all your values there are strings)

```
 var shiftDetailQuery = from l in logsheet
                                   join sd in shiftDetail on l.crew equals sd.crewID into LeftJoin
                                   (from sd_sub in LeftJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                    where (sd_sub.time_on >= dateArg.addDays(-1) && sd_sub.time_on <= dateArg) && (sd_sub.time_off > dateArg || sd_sub.time_off == DateTime.MinValue))
                                   select new MRxCaseSearchResults
                                   {
                                       CaseNumber = l.case_number,
                                       Crew = l.crew,
                                       Ambulance = sd_sub.Ambulance ?? string.empty
                                       OfficerNo = sd_sub.officer_no ?? string.empty
                                   };
```

Comment: What does the "??" stand for?Here,ambulance is Int16 and officer_no is Int - how do I modify it? Also,I am unable to convert this to LINQ: `and sd.time_on between dateadd(d,-1,'2013-05-30 21:48:04.000') and '2013-05-30 21:48:04.000' and (sd.time_off > '2013-05-30 21:48:04.000' or sd.time_off is null)`

Comment: Ah you don't want ?? then that basically means use the left value, but if its null, use the right value.

Comment: Where does that hardcoded date in dateadd(d,-1,'2013-05-30 21:48:04.000') come from? Is that passed in somewhere, or is it the same every time?

Comment: this query is in a stored proc...the date is an argument

Comment: I think something like what I placed in the edit should do it. Note I assume you pass DateTime.MinValue since DateTime cannot be null.